# Getting an error when retrieving data from SugarCRM

Tags: php, wordpress, sugarcrm

I retrieve data through SugarCRM, then it displays an error of this type:

```
 $accountParams = array('session' => $session_id, 'module_name' => 'Leads','query' => "id like 5180dfeb-8a3f-51ca-2eaa-510921ef1da6", 'order_by' => '', 'deleted' => 0);
    $accountId = $soapclient->call('get_entry_list', $accountParams);
    var_dump($accountId);


array
  'result_count' => int -1
  'error' => 
    array
      'number' => string '40' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Access Denied' (length=13)
      'description' => string 'You do not have access' (length=22)

array
  'id' => string 'nmrcjiso5b2aqq7htc9oski9j7' (length=26)
  'error' => 
    array
      'number' => string '0' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'No Error' (length=8)
      'description' => string 'No Error' (length=8)
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with SugarCRM, but it may help if we can see the code you're using to make a request - edit it into your question. As an aside, the use of abbreviated 'text speak' is generally discouraged here - so expand 'plz' and so forth to real English where you can - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two things possibily going on...

1. Make sure you have permissions to that record and the Leads module in generak
2. I see a typo in your code, change...

   ```
   'query' => "id like 5180dfeb-8a3f-51ca-2eaa-510921ef1da6"
   ```

...to this

```
    'query' => "id = '5180dfeb-8a3f-51ca-2eaa-510921ef1da6'"
```

...or better yet, use the get_entry() call

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework#Call:_get_entry%28%29

Comment: If i write this way than it display boolean flase

'query' => "id = '5180dfeb-8a3f-51ca-2eaa-510921ef1da6'"